# What is the meaning of the phrase "slaved out"

Tags: american-english

As I was reading a character's biography :

> Jack, a small orphan child on transport ship that crashed on the Pitch
>   Black planet. During the movie it is discovered that the child dresses
>   like a boy, but is actually female.
>
> In the second installment of the series, we discover that she attempts
>   to replicate Riddick's eyes and fate by joining a bounty hunter crew.
>   **She was slaved out**, and when attempting to escape murdered her captives, and sent to a prison.
>
> At the end of Chronicles, she is killed during the fight with the Lord
>   Marshall.

I was wondering what "slaved out" exactly means. I tried to ask my friends, whose English is way better than mine, but they could not provide an answer.

Comment: *slave* 6. (often foll by: *away*) to work like a slave http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slave

Comment: @Kris, thanks, was raping involved, especially?

Comment: I take 'slaved out' to mean 'sold into slavery' or perhaps 'rented out as a slave'. Incidentally, the text you quoted is full of grammatical mistakes and continuity errors; for example, it should have said "murdered her **captors**, and **was** sent to a prison". The first sentence lacks an active verb. What exactly does "she attempts to replicate Riddick's eyes and fate" mean?

Comment: @ErikKowal Thanks for the explanation and corrections, i copied this content from IMDB. I added a dialogue in my question, which will help you understand it better (the eyes part)

Answer (score 4):

*Slave out* likely refers to the archaic practice of forcing criminals, prisoners of war, or victims of kidnapping into slavery. From the transitive verb definition of *[slave](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slave)*:

> transitive verb
>
> 1 archaic :  enslave
>
> *merriam-webster.com*

The dialogue of *[Desert World Allegiances](https://books.google.com/books?id=6omgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA225&dq=%22slaved%20out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=nco1VdrNMZK3yASfsYHABw&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22slaved%20out%22&f=false)*, by Lena Gala, suggests criminals sentenced to slavery:

> “That we are,” Naite agreed. “And we need to make changes, but there
>   isn't a better solution. And I'm saying that as someone who has both
>   survived a long ***slavery sentence*** and is facing another."
>
> "You ... What?" Shan asked, his stomach souring at Naite's casual
>   attitude toward slavery after all these horrors.
>
> “Why would you be ***slaved out***?” Temar sat up, his face alarmed.
>
> “I'm likely to be ***slaved out*** to you, Temar. I don't have any training, and I definitely don't have money for fines, ... It's
>   that or hand over half my pay for the rest of my life, and trust me,
>   I'd rather be ***slaved out*** for a time and have it done and over with.”
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

The dialogue of *[The Doctrine of Presence](https://books.google.com/books?id=VwUPJnKKGG0C&pg=PT146&dq=can%27t%20happens%20%22slaved%20out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=V881VdfVLY-lyASo_oGwBQ&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=can't%20happens%20%22slaved%20out%22&f=false)*, by Benjamin Vance, suggest prisoners of war pressed into slavery:

> "...I don't know about combat, but if that happens I'll keep my head
>   down and let you guys take care of it.”
>
> “What if we can't take care of it? What happens to you?”
>
> “I get killed too, or ***slaved out***, who the shit knows in this world,
>   from one minute to the next with these crazy Islamic fascists loose?"
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

The description of *[Native American Adoption, Captivity, and Slavery in Changing Contexts](https://books.google.com/books?id=kQfHAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA62&dq=%22slaved%20out%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=_NI1VdSRO4WMyATXwoDICg&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=woman%20%22slaved%20out%22&f=false)*, by Max Carocci, et al, suggests kidnapping victims forced into slavery:

> Also, the most vulnerable populations such as the mission Indians of
>   Spanish Florida had been ***slaved out***. Slave catchers were simply
>   running out of people to enslave.
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine